# When adding keybindings to a JTree, Why am I forced to make each Action it's own class?

Tags: java, swing, action, jtree, key-bindings

**Question: When adding keybindings to a JTree, Why am I forced to make each Action it's own class?** 
**Why can't I have have each action use a single Action class?**
To understand my question/issue, let me start off by explaining my Short Self Contained Example of the Problem below.

```
addKeyBindings(JTree tree) has the following 2 lines commented out. 
//Action addsiblingnodeaction = new RightClickNodeAction("Add SiblingNode");
//Action addchildnodeaction = new RightClickNodeAction("Add ChildNode");
/*These use 1 action class, to do 2 different actions. (I want this because I 
find the code to be less verbose)
(They're commented out because they don't work for keybindings)
(The reason I ask question, is because they DO work for JPopupMenu)*/
```

**The Real Question is Why does the above //commented out code// not work for keybindings?** (In my example I included a JPopupMenu to show that the above commented out code works for JPopupMenu, and in my mind should also work for keybindings) (The only way I was able to get the keybindings to work was to make a AbstractAction class for each Action, which you can see in the example code below)

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class StackExchangeQuestion2 {
     public static void main(String[] args){
     StackExchangeQuestion2 workaround = new StackExchangeQuestion2();
     //workaround = compiler didn't like me throwing constructor code in main
     }//end main

StackExchangeQuestion2(){
     JTree tree = new JTree();   
     initRightClickMenu(tree);//purpose of existance is to show Action Code is accurate
     addKeyBindings(tree);

     JFrame window = new JFrame();
     window.getRootPane().setContentPane(tree);
     window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     window.setTitle("Stack Exchange Question");
     window.setSize(400,500);//variable parameters would be best
     window.setVisible(true);           
     }//constructor

private void initRightClickMenu(JTree tree){
     JPopupMenu rightclickmenu = new JPopupMenu();   
     Action addsiblingnodeaction = new RightClickNodeAction("Add SiblingNode");
     Action addchildnodeaction = new RightClickNodeAction("Add ChildNode");
     rightclickmenu.add(addsiblingnodeaction);
     rightclickmenu.add(addchildnodeaction);
     tree.setComponentPopupMenu(rightclickmenu);        
}

private void addSiblingNode(){
System.out.println("sibling node added");}
private void addChildNode(){
System.out.println("child node added");}     


private void addKeyBindings(JTree tree){
 //Action addsiblingnodeaction = new RightClickNodeAction("Add SiblingNode");
 Action addsiblingnodeaction = new AddSiblingNodeAction("Add SiblingNode");
    tree.getActionMap().put("Add SiblingNode", addsiblingnodeaction);
    tree.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "Add SiblingNode");    
 //Action addchildnodeaction = new RightClickNodeAction("Add ChildNode");
 Action addchildnodeaction = new AddChildNodeAction("Add ChildNode");    
    tree.getActionMap().put("Add ChildNode", addchildnodeaction);
    tree.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "Add ChildNode");
}//end addKeyBindins    

private class AddSiblingNodeAction extends AbstractAction{      
    AddSiblingNodeAction(String name){super(name);}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {    addSiblingNode();   }}

private class AddChildNodeAction extends AbstractAction{      
    AddChildNodeAction(String name){super(name);}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {    addChildNode();     }}    

private class RightClickNodeAction extends AbstractAction{      
    RightClickNodeAction(String name){super(name);}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Add SiblingNode"))addSiblingNode();
    if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Add ChildNode"))addChildNode();     }}
}//end class
```

Comment: If you slap this working self contained code in an IDE, it works as expected, however, if in `addKeyBindings(JTree tree)` you switch the commented Action code, it stops working/nothing happens. (your looking for a message to print out on press ENTER/SPACE)

Comment: hum adding `System.out.println("Action Command is: "+ae.getActionCommand());` to class RightClickNodeAction. AND switching the 2 commented out lines seems helpful in debugging/figureing out, the ActionCommand String is null for some reason for keyBindings (to JTree's input Map), but as expected for JPopupMenu

Comment: `Action` doesn't set the `actionCommand` is it is always `null`.  Instead you could try getting the `NAME` property (`get(NAME)`) and compare that

Comment: actionCommand is not null for JPopupMenu, which I mentioned in 2nd comment, but thanks for giving me ideas of what java docs to look at, maybe there's some way to set it durring construction.

Comment: *"actionCommand is not null for JPopupMenu"* - It should be

Comment: How could I set the ActionCommand? I'm searching the Action API atm, Or if you get what I'm trying to do, I'm open to alternative ways of doing the same thing. Also I should clarify the ActionCommand string (in comment 2) isn't null, it's empty.

Comment: Try something like `addchildnodeaction.putValue(Action.ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, addchildnodeaction.getValue(Action.NAME));` after you've created the action...

Comment: And, yes, adding an action to the JPopupMenu does seem to, for some reason, seed the `ActionCommand` of the `ActionEvent` with the `NAME` property if the `ACTION_COMMAND_KEY` is not set...

Comment: :) thanks for your help, by reading deeper into Action API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#ACTION_COMMAND_KEY    I'm able to answer my own question for the 1st time. Heh it was basically just as you suggested btw. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Because I'm doing it wrong, I'm not forced to do it one way.

```
private class RightClickNodeAction extends AbstractAction{      
    RightClickNodeAction(String name){super(name);
    putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, name); 
    }//end constructor
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
   //System.out.println("Action Command is: "+ae.getActionCommand());
   //the above comment verified it worked as expected + testing
if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Add SiblingNode"))addSiblingNode();
if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Add ChildNode"))addChildNode();     }}
```

Comment: I just had to add `putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, name);` to the constructor, and it fixed it/initialized ActionEvent ae so that ae.getActionCommand had a valid value in all cases